# How can I block a web address on my server or redirect it?

Tags: redirect, blocking

I want to block or redirect a user accessing a web address like this on my server:

```
https://my.website.com/404javascript.js
```

Somebody keeps trying to run: `404javascript.js` (which does not exist) on my website, this logs a Zend error. This fills up my error log, it also looks suspicious.

Is it possible to block a web address or redirect? If so, what's the most secure method?

I have looked at adding a DNS redirect, but this appears only to work at domain name level.

```
3130A72A-BC7C-239A-4EED-2DA6C5C24F13: Request Parameters--Array ( [controller] => 404javascript.js [action] => index [module] => default )
```

I want to bounce or redirect users that try to access: `https://my.website.com/404javascript.js`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: No problem, it looks like this can't be done anyhow. A developer has told us that these things cannot be blocked or redirected. So there you go. We'll just write a script to delete the error logs.